# Tomcat is working properly but not able to deploy war file , gives me 404

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

```
30-Jun-2017 15:14:30.436 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@2cae1ed]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4869)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5001)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@3df89c05]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:709)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:113)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:717)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:419)
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
        at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:65)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:425)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:193)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:180)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:111)
        ... 17 more
```

This is the exception i've been getting,surfed many links but not able to fix it.If I deploy any other war files other than this ,they are working well.Previously when i was using spring version 4.0.6 it was working good.I upgraded it to 4.3.6 version then onwards its not getting deployed in tomcat server.Even I made rollback again to 4.0.6 version but not working.Don't know where I'm missing.Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: "Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)... at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:425)" -- Sounds like you have a corrupt jar.

Comment: I have done clean and install but no use.The thing is that its working good in IDE but when i try to deploy it in ubuntu server its not working

Comment: Bad jar maybe not be local but remote, so it's working on your machine because you have a local version of the jar that is good. One solution is to checksum  (`sha1sum` for example) the exploded war and compare with the deployed one on your ubuntu server.